# How do I make a recursive string detector in c++ using only 2 parameters

Tags: c++, string, recursion

```
int charFrequency( string str, char c,int subscript) {  
  
  if (subscript >= str.length())
  {
    return 0; 
  }
  else if (str[subscript] == c)

  {
    
    return 1 + charFrequency(str, c, subscript+ 1);

  }
  else
  {
    return charFrequency(str, c, subscript+ 1);
  }
}
```

this is my recursive function it is working nothing wrong with it, however I have to modify this to make it work with only two parameters the string and the char c I can't have the extra subscript parameter in the function but I can figure out how to make it work, I guess I'm mental blocked from doing it this way. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Typical way to do something recursively is to make the recursive case do something "smaller".  Then, eventually, the something "smaller" becomes nothing at all, and you're done.  You can think of it that way, or you can think of it "upside down": What's the smallest case of all: Nothing to do.  What's the _next-to_ smallest case, and how do you get from there to the smallest case in one easy step?

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified but basically it takes in any string, as well as any char, then it will output how many times that char was in that string for example CharFrequency("aaaa",a) the output would be 4

Comment: `string str` is passed by value. You could make the string slightly smaller each time rather than iterating it. Note: This is a really crappy use of recursion. I'm assuming this is an assignment and you have no choice, but when you get out into real-life programming, don't do this to yourself.

Comment: @Nicholas *"I should've clarified"* -- you use the past tense as if this is something you cannot change. Think present tense: you *should* clarify (by using the "Edit" link to add that information to your question).

Comment: FYI, a *recursive string detector* is a lot different than a character frequency function.  There are many rules to apply to see if the input is a string (versus a number or symbols).  I recommend you change your questions title more appropriately.

Comment: Also, if only want to use 2 parameters than use `std::string`.  You can get the length of the `std::string` using the `length` method.  The `std::string` doesn't require a null terminator.  Your recursive function could go on forever if a nul terminator character is not found.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int charFreq(const char * str, char c) {
  if (str[0] == '\0') {
    return 0; 
    
  } else if (str[0] == c) {
    return 1 + charFreq(str + 1, c);

  } else {
    return charFreq(str + 1, c);
  }
}

int main()
{
    string smt = "Hello World";
    
    cout << "freq: " << charFreq(smt.c_str(), 'l') << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

With the str + 1 you move the pointer in char array which is accessible from std::string trough .c_str(). Bevare of the ending '\0' character which are standard part of c-style strings. But if you supply some regular char array it may lead to infinite loop or program crash.

Updated version with string:

```
int charFreq(string str, char c) {
  if (str.length() == 0) {
    return 0; 
    
  } else if (str[0] == c) {
    return 1 + charFreq(str.substr(1), c);

  } else {
    return charFreq(str.substr(1), c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, However the problem that I'm facing as was similar to my uploaded code was that I cannot change my parameters I need to keep my str variable as a string and my c variable as char. my apologies for not mentioning this